# laravel foreach loop in controller

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

i have a problem about looping data in controller (laravel 4). my code is like this:

```
$owner = Input::get('owner');
$count = Input::get('count');
$product = Product::whereOwnerAndStatus($owner, 0)->take($count)->get();
```

when i want to use foreach to loop for $product result with code like this:

```
foreach ($product->sku as $sku) {
    // Code Here
}
```

the result is returning error
**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sku**

so, i try to improvise a little with this code:

```
foreach ($product as $items) {
    foreach ($items->sku as $sku) {
        // Code Here        
    }
}
```

the code returning error like this:
**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

is there someone who could help me solve this?

Comment: `whereOwnerAndStatus` never seen that syntax before. Does that work? Where in the docs is that?

Comment: How did you pass the `$products` to your view ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will throw an error:

```
foreach ($product->sku as $sku){ 
// Code Here
}
```

because you cannot loop a model with a specific column (`$product->sku`) from the table.

So, you must loop on the whole model:

```
foreach ($product as $p) {
// code
}
```

Inside the loop you can retrieve whatever column you want just adding `->[column_name]`

```
foreach ($product as $p) {
echo $p->sku;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your `$product` has no data because the `Eloquent` model returns NULL. It's probably because you have used `whereOwnerAndStatus` which seems wrong and if there were data in `$product` then it would not work in your first example because `get()` returns a collection of multiple models but that is not the case. The second example throws error because `foreach` didn't get any data. So I think it should be something like this:

```
$owner = Input::get('owner');
$count = Input::get('count');
$products = Product::whereOwner($owner, 0)->take($count)->get();
```

Further you may also make sure if `$products` has data:

```
if($product) {
    return View:make('viewname')->with('products', $products);
}
```

Then in the `view`:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    // If Product has sku (collection object, probably related models)
    foreach ($product->sku as $sku) {
        // Code Here        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The view (blade template): Inside the loop you can retrieve whatever column you looking for

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)
   {{$product->sku}}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `sku` just a property of the `Product` model? If so:

```
$products = Product::whereOwnerAndStatus($owner, 0)->take($count)->get();

foreach ($products as $product ) {
  // Access $product->sku here...
}
```

Or is `sku` a relationship to another model? If that is the case, then, as long as your relationship is setup properly, you code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allData = Model::where('status', 1)->get();
                foreach ($allData as $data){
                    $data->status = 0;
                    $data->update();
                }
```

Here every **$data** is single data and **$allData** contains full collection.

Answer (score 0):

******using foreach on table******

for me

```
@foreach($products as $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$data->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->price}}</td>
            </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit multiple data in laravel
You can use this for updating multiple data in laravel, which i have tested it and it works for me.
also remember i used relatationship here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg6hx.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And also, please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide. Your code is hardly readable without formatting.